# Android Studio 3.3 missing jetpack creation option

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack

Android Studio 3.3 (Canary 12) does not have an option called "Activity & Fragment + ViewModel" and related configuration to create a Jetpack app (running on Windows 10).

Any suggestions?

Comment: [As you've already done](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116846620), probably the best option it to open a bug on Android Studio's issuetracker, and continue the investigation there.

Answer (score 7):

This is a late follow-up, but I am experiencing the same bug on the now stable version 3.3 of Android Studio ("Activity & Fragment + ViewModel" does not appear on creation of a Jetpack application).

My current workaround is to create an application with "No Activity" and add the activity after the project has been created by going to New -> Activity -> Fragment + Viewmodel and adding it that way.

I assume it is a bug, not a feature and am looking for other posts about this issue. Not sure if Google is aware of it.